# Fonts are rejected by Firefox 44

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, webfonts

When updating to Firefox 44 it started to reject all our fonts, both WOFF and TTF. I also have the error in Firefox Nightly (47).

Everything worked well in Firefox 43 and below.

I get these error messages:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer
downloadable font: Layout: Bad lookup flags 8
downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse lookup 0
downloadable font: GPOS: Failed to parse lookup list table
downloadable font: Layout: DFLT table doesn't satisfy the spec. for script tag DFLT
```

I'm not sure how to debug this issue, and I can't find any information directly related to Firefox 44.

I can't verify the fonts with http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ since the fonts are branded and blacklisted on the site.

The `@font-face` rules looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Amperserif Disp";
  src: url('../fonts/amperserif/disp/amperserif_disp.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/amperserif/disp/amperserif_disp.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/amperserif/disp/amperserif_disp.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/amperserif/disp/amperserif_disp.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Maybe correlated: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1244693 "this is indeed a font error; it includes LangSysRecord entries under the 'DFLT' script, which violates the OpenType spec. (Those records belong under the 'latn' script tag.) - The new revision of OTS (OpenType Sanitizer) in FF44 has become stricter about errors in the OpenType layout tables, and now rejects the font."

Comment: Sounds like the same problem we have. Add an answer so I can accept it